# Can this query be changed to add an or?

Tags: google-app-maker

I'm not sure how to change this query in google app maker language

```
 var query = app.models.folders.newQuery();
  query.filters.requestId._equals = request;
  query.filters.filecount._equals = null;
  var total = 0;
  var recx = query.run();
```

So right now it is the equivalent of

```
select * from folders 
where requestID = request
and filecount = null
```

But I would like to know if there is a way to change it to the equivalent of

```
select * from folders 
where requestID = request
and (filecount = null or filecount < 0)
```

Maybe by using query.where?

Comment: Query where is certainly possible, but you will also need to preset the parameters for the query. Also keep in mind that App Maker will be gone in about 11 months, so I would start exploring alternatives. The query where expression would be rather similar to your last SQL statement.

Comment: that's a good point markus, rather than fighting with the appmaker interface maybe I should just iterate towards a different format

Answer (score 0):

You could try by just adding another filter to your query:

```
var query = app.models.folders.newQuery();
query.filters.requestId._equals = request;
query.filters.filecount._equals = null;
query.filters.filecount._lessThan = 0;
var total = 0;
var recx = query.run();
```